# RAM, JSC, Views, UI and JS usage table appearing whenever I launch my react native app. How to remove this table?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to develop a mobile app for shake gesture in react-native. Everything is working fine, but RAM, JSC, Views, UI and JS usage table is appearing in iPhone7. I am not sure is it related to this app or specific to phone. Because this is appearing only in iPhone7 and not in iPhone 7Plus and Samsung s7 in those devices I tested.

I tried to remove the app and reinstalled and restarted the device.

Answer (score 17):

It's from the Expo simulator. Physically shake your iPhone and tap Hide Perf Monitor from the options menu

Answer (score 8):

In the Simulator, tap `Cmd D` > Hide Perf Monitor

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

From file > open simulator > change the iPhone type, the RAM and JSC notification will disappear. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Shake the device using the simulator menu and disable performance monitor from the overlay menu from within the simulator UI

Answer (score 0):

Pressing `command ⌘ + D` keys now shows `Toggle performance monitor` instead of `Hide Perf Monitor` option for iOS simulator.

[image: iOS simulator cmd + d option for showing/hiding performance monitor]